# Syntax errors during compilation

Tags: java, checkbox

I have done some research and I think I have this nested wrong or possibly the init() header is not right? I have been working on this same problem for two days now, but cannot seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. This assignment was due yesterday but I cannot get it debugged to send in.

I keep getting this error:
    ShippingCostCalcApplet.java:35: error:  expected
      Checkbox hiddenBox = new Checkbox(" "),true,codeGroup);
                                             ^
    ShippingCostCalcApplet.java:35: error: illegal start of expression
      Checkbox hiddenBox = new Checkbox(" "),true,codeGroup);
                                                 ^
    ShippingCostCalcApplet.java:35: error: ';' expected
      Checkbox hiddenBox = new Checkbox(" "),true,codeGroup);
                                                           ^
3 errors

Here is the code:

```
public class ShippingCostCalcApplet extends Applet implements ItemListener
{
   double price, shippingCost;
   int code;
   Color purple = new Color (72, 61, 139);

   public void init()
   { 
   Label promptLabel = new Label("Enter the total order price (do not use punctuation or dollar signs).");
      TextField priceField = new TextField(20);

   Label codeLabel = new Label("Select your method of shipping:");

   CheckboxGroup codeGroup = new CheckboxGroup();
      Checkbox overnightBox = new Checkbox("Priorityovernight shipping",false,codeGroup);
      Checkbox expressBox = new Checkbox("Express shipping 2 business days",false,codeGroup);
      Checkbox standardBox = new Checkbox("Standard shipping 3-7 business days",false,codeGroup);
      Checkbox hiddenBox = new Checkbox(" "),true,codeGroup);

   Label outputLabel = new Label("Select your shipping rate.");


         setBackground(purple);
         setForeground(Color.white);
         add(promptLabel);
         add(priceField);
         priceField.requestFocus();
         priceField.setForeground(Color.black);
         add(codeLabel);
         add(overnightBox);
         overnightBox.addItemListener(this);
         add(expressBox);
         expressBox.addItemListener(this);
         add(standardBox);
         standardBox.addItemListener(this);
         add(outputLabel);
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the extra bracket.

```
Checkbox hiddenBox = new Checkbox(" "),true,codeGroup);
```

to

```
Checkbox hiddenBox = new Checkbox(" ",true,codeGroup);
```

Comment: That was an error, I can't believe I missed that! I still had the error after fixing it though. I am very new to java.